# Assigning a variable a "range" in a diamond square algorithm

Tags: r, matrix

I'm looking for a way to make variables have an allowable range that they can be placed in on a diamond square algorithm based terrain. The variables start off as a list of just the letters a - z, and become a randomly distributed matrix of 1,000 by 1,000. The diamond square algorithm (DSQA for ease) I copied from an online source, and while I understand *how* it creates the terrain as a concept, I don't understand what bits of the code are effecting what. Either way, I get an output of a terrain, both as a 3D terrain map and a 2D colour based contour map.

So what I need to do is create a range for the variables, e.g. A has a range of 0.3, beginning at a "height" of 0, B a range of 0.3 beginning at a height of .2 etc.

What I can't figure out, even conceptually, is how to do give these variables a range for the DSQA, as up to this point I have created the two sets of code (the matrix and the algorithm output) totally separately, and have no idea how to merge them. I have been told to mostly "ignore" the algorithm code and just use the output which looks like this: [image: Contour Output]

I need to change the size of the contour output to match my existing matrix (1,000 by 1,000) which I also am not sure where to do, whether I should just do it in the algorithm code, or create the matrix then feed that matrix to the algorithm, or visa versa?

My code is currently pretty clunky, for which I apologise, it's got multiple repeats of the same base matrix being changed, but I've uploaded them as text files to [**here**](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AvglJUjI3dGInTzKyJGvdcoj-hoL) if they're of any use (it obviously only has to be run once to get a matrix and an algorithm, I just have to get multiple repeats for what I'm doing). There's every chance I'm just missing or can't think of a really simple command that would let me do this, but right now it is beyond my skills, and I've bit off far more than I can chew!

Any help would be amazingly appreciated.

**EDIT:**  A more manageable section of code based on the same matrix but only 5x5.

```
#Create Species Vector
species.v<-letters[1:5]
species.v<-as.character(species.v)
#Check species Vector
species.v

#Matrix creation (Random)
orig.neutral<- matrix(sample(species.v,25,replace=TRUE),
                      nrow=5,
                      ncol=5)

#Neutral Matrix
neutral.v0<-orig.neutral

#Create dice roll for replacement
dice.vector<-c(1:10)
dice.vector

#For loop and Ifs for replacement/immigration/speciation
for (i in 1:100) {{dice.roll<-sample(dice.vector,1)}###For Loop with IF functions
  if(dice.roll <= 7) {
    neutral.v0[sample(length(neutral.v0),1)]<-as.character(sample(neutral.v0,1))
  } else if (dice.roll > 7 & dice.roll < 10){
    neutral.v0[sample(length(neutral.v0),1)]<-as.character(sample(immigration.vec,1))
  } else if (dice.roll == 10){
    elIdx = sample(length(neutral.v0),1) #index of a randomly selected element
    neutral.v0[elIdx] = paste(neutral.v0[elIdx], "2", sep="")
  }}
```

Comment: I'm so confused. Can you (a) reduce this to a *minimal* problem? Do you really need a list of a-z and a 1,000 x 1,000 matrix to show the problem o would three letters and a 10x10 matrix work? What is your input? It seems like you think the answer is very simple, which can only mean you are sharing *far* too much irrelevant information.

Comment: "I just have to get multiple repeats for what I'm doing" sounds like you need a `for` loop or `replicate`.

Comment: "what I need to do is create a range for the variables" is more confusing - do you need to randomly draw variables from specified ranges? Or are you trying to test these variables to see *if* they lie in a specified range? Something else? You say they *"start off as just a list of letters"* and they *"become a 1000x1000 matrix"*. Does this list of letters have values and it is those values that have the range? Or is it every value in the resulting matrix? Do you have 1 matrix per letter or all the letters become a single matrix?

Comment: So first, thanks for trying to decipher my gibberish, it's appreciated.

Comment: In answer to your first question, yes, what I need to know could well be minimalised:  

Let's say I have a matrix of 5x5, my "species" list is 5 letters a - e. I run a code that randomly distributes these letters into the 5x5 matrix. And then run a series of if functions to cause random replacement based on chance.

Comment: The diamond square algorithm could (I guess) be seen as a single peak, with the centre being "5" high, out to the edges being "0" high. What I need is for each species to have a specific "range" on that peak. Then during the creation of the matrix, I'd at an "if" loop for something along the lines of "if(letter) is in the correct range, it can stay, if not run replacement loop again".

Comment: So in my mind I need to assign the letters a range they can "survive" in, e.g. a = 0 - 1,  b = 1 - 2, c = 2 - 3, d = 3 - 4, e = 4 - 5. Then add a check in my replacement loop to make sure what has just gone in that spot is within its range (which is just replacing a random element of the matrix, with a random sample of the matrix itself).

Comment: So my two main problems are: 

**1)** merging the matrix and diamond square algorithm so that the ranges "exist" (do I just tell a diamond square algorithm it is now 1000 x 1000, do I create a blank matrix, overlay it onto the algorithm output, and then run my creation/replacement code with checks to populate it?)

**2)** assigning a range to the letters that they can exist in. I should be able to figure out the if function just fine based on the assigning function, as it's just checking that has happened, so it's just the assignment I need to know.

Comment: Apologies for the multiple comments, can't chat yet. Being a beginner has a lot of drawbacks beyond just not having a clue what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what I was doing wrong, which was instead of taking the output of the diamond square algorithm as a matrix of values, I was trying to think about overlaying a different matrix over the top. The long and short was that I only have to refer to the diamond square algorithm output matrix, not directly use it as a "base" for a second higher matrix.

Ultimately to give the variables a range, I have to put them into a data frame with the range next to them (e.g. col 1 = a, col 2 = min range, col 3 = max range), then add a check into my if functions to check that the location a is place is within the range of the min/max I've assigned to it.